# Python - Run multiple async functions simultaneously

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm essentially making a pinger, that makes has a 2d list, of key / webhook pairs, and after pinging a key, send the response to a webhook

the 2d list goes as follows:

```
some_list = [["key1", "webhook1"], ["key2", "webhook2"]]
```

My program is essentially a loop, and I'm not too sure how I can rotate the `some_list` data, in the function.

Here's a little demo of what my script looks like:

```py
async def do_ping(some_pair):
    async with aiohttps.ClientSession() as s:
        tasks = await gen_tasks(s, some_pair)
        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks*)
        sleep(10)
        await do_ping(some_pair)
```

I've tried:

```py
async def main(): 
    for entry in some_list: 
        asyncio.run(do_ping(entry))
```

but due to the `do_ping` function being a self-calling loop, it just calls the first one over and over again, and never gets to the ones after it. Hoping to find a solution to this, whether it's threading or alike, and if you have a better way of structuring `some_list` values (which I assume would be a dictionary), feel free to drop that feedback as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You made your method recursive `await do_ping(some_pair)`, it never ends for the loop in `main` to continue. I would restructure the application like this:

```
async def do_ping(some_pair):
    async with aiohttps.ClientSession() as s:
        while True:
            tasks = await gen_tasks(s, some_pair)
            results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
            await asyncio.sleep(10)


async def main(): 
    tasks = [do_ping(entry) for entry in some_list]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Alternatively you could move the repeat and sleeping logic into the `main`:

```
async def do_ping(some_pair):
    async with aiohttps.ClientSession() as s:
        tasks = await gen_tasks(s, some_pair)
        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


async def main(): 
    while True:
        tasks = [do_ping(entry) for entry in some_list]
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        await asyncio.sleep(10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

You could also start the tasks before doing a call to sleep, and gather them afterwards. That would make the pings more consistently start at 10 second intervals instead of being 10 seconds + the time it takes to gather the results:

```
async def main(): 
    while True:
        tasks = [
            asyncio.create_task(do_ping(entry))
            for entry in some_list
        ]
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        await asyncio.wait(tasks)
```

---

EDIT As pointed out by [creolo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4614050/creolo) you should only create a single `ClientSession` object. See https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html

> Session encapsulates a connection pool (connector instance) and supports keepalives by default. Unless you are connecting to a large, unknown number of different servers over the lifetime of your application, it is suggested you use a single session for the lifetime of your application to benefit from connection pooling.

```
async def do_ping(session, some_pair):
    tasks = await gen_tasks(session, some_pair)
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

async def main(): 
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        while True:
            tasks = [
                asyncio.create_task(do_ping(session, entry))
                for entry in some_list
            ]
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
            await asyncio.wait(tasks)
```

Comment: But wouldn't that cause for the pinger to run only once per pair?

Comment: @neiii Notice that I added in a `while True`. Each `do_ping` task will run forever unless there is an exception or signal interrupt.

Comment: this actually works, thanks so much!

Comment: @neiii glad to help! Also do note, when using asyncio its very important to do `await asyncio.sleep(10)` rather than `time.sleep(10)`. The latter will block the interpreter and will block any other tasks from doing work.

Comment: It is also recommended to use a single ClientSession() over the lifetime of the application as stated here: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html